# Plot results of logistic regression with interaction terms (Python Scikit-Learn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I need for educational purposes (I want to show overfitting) to create a plot of logistic regression with interaction terms of high degrees. I have only two variables in my dataset (so I can plot the results), say X and Y, and I have to include all terms of the degrees up to 30, so X**30, X**29, X**29*Y and so on. I know how to build a logistic regression in this case (using PolynomialFeatures) but I don't know how to plot it without much coding. Have somebody any Idea or perhaps already done something of the kind? Thanks in advance.